# How do I add a solid material inside edges?

Tags: mesh, materials

[image: lines]

I want to add a solid kind of mesh inside the chosen edges. I dont know much about modeling so if someone could help me it would be great. Outer lines will be used for different kind of material that I have a tutorial for. So outer edges should not be touched. Im new to this.

Comment: If you mean that you want to fill the mesh, select one of them and press F

Comment: ok ill try to do that

Comment: I  filled it. but can i give it a texture

Comment: to give it a material, select this face you've created, go in the Properties panel (right panel) > Material, create a new material and click on Assign

Comment: thanks alot dude